# Accidentaly deleted all aliases. How can I restore them?

Tags: restore, alias

I accidentally deleted all aliases with `unalias` utility. There were some useful aliases that I want back (with `--color` option etc), but I don't want to type them again. Is there a simple way to restore them?

EDIT: I want only the aliases that came with the 14.04 installation.

Comment: since when does unalias delete them? It just unloads them from the session(?)

Comment: indeed. I should read better :/

Comment: We all have such days. And @choas is the one getting better from it since he will rake in the rep ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`unalias` just removes the alias for the running session. Just start another new terminal or use that command:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```